# Unable to create DB2 Procedure through command line

Tags: sql, db2, procedure

I am trying to create a procedure to do a blanket revoking of executeauth for procedures from a schema. This is in line with trying to secure a non-restricted database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_REV
    LANGUAGE SQL
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE v_NAME VARCHAR(400);
        FOR v1 AS
        c1 CURSOR FOR
        select specificname from SYSCAT.ROUTINEAUTH where grantee='PUBLIC' and schema='SYSPROC' and routinetype='P'
        DO
            SET v_NAME = specificname;
            SET v_GrantQuery = 'revoke execute on specific procedure '|| v_NAME ||' from PUBLIC';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_GrantQuery;
        END FOR;
    END#
```

and this is the command I run to process the file with the code above.

```
db2 -td# -svf RoutineAuthRevoke.db2
```

However, I keep running into this error

```
SQL0553N An object cannot be created with the schema name "SYSFUN  ". LINE NUMBER=1. SQLSTATE 42939
```

I'm fairly new to DB2 and this is my first foray into writing db2 procedure scripts. Would anyone be able to spot the "SYSFUN  " because I sure as hell can't. The only other way I can revoke 310 entries from SYSPROC for PUBLIC is through a batch file and I figured, procedures might be a cleaner way of achieving this. I would really appreciate any help with either this error or with the code itself.

Comment: try to specify and schema: CREATE PROCEDURE SCHM1.PROC_REV  .....

Comment: Please edit your question. The example won't compile becase v_GrantQuery is undefined. Does the database have a SECADM?  What rights and authoritities does your account have? Does the error happen at CREATE or CALL? Specify the *server* db2level output in plain text. Follow documented rules for `REVOKE (routine privileges)` statement including "It is not possible to revoke the EXECUTE privilege on a function or method defined with schema 'SYSIBM' or 'SYSFUN'", also the REVOKE should be used only for routines that are not defined in a module.

Comment: @mao Yes, the database has SECADM. Also I managed to revoke the executeauth for SYSFUN procedures from PUBLIC. But I did that through writing a bat file which ran
db2 -v "revoke execute on specific procedure %%x from PUBLIC"; where %%x was a string from an array of strings which were from SYSFUN i.e GET_SAR, PUT_SAR

Comment: @mshabou I get it now, since I come from a C++ background, I thought that when you create a procedure, CREATE PROCEDURE XXXX, XXXX is just a function name. I did not know that it was actually holding a schema location. Thanks!

Comment: @mao The error happens at CREATE. But I understand why it has the error now. Thank you all for your inputs. Having to do this while not being a DBA nor having prior experience with DB2 is really confusing and I'm doing what I can with just skimming through documentation and other Stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of problems.

You can't create a routine in the `SYSFUN` schema as the error message shows. You get this message because the statement `VALUES CURRENT SCHEMA` returns SYSFUN in your session. You must either run the `SET SCHEMA SOME_VALID_SCHEMA_NAME` statement before `CREATE` or use fully qualified routine name like `SOME_VALID_SCHEMA_NAME.PROC_REV`.

Variable `v_GrantQuery` is not defined in the routine.

According to the syntax of [REVOKE (routine privileges) statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-revoke-routine-privileges), you should generate the `REVOKE` statement using fully qualified routine name and with `RESTRICT` clause at the end. The easiest way to do it with a compound statement (you don't need to create a routine for that):

```
BEGIN
    FOR v1 AS
        select 'REVOKE EXECUTE ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE "' || schema ||'"."'|| specificname || '" FROM PUBLIC RESTRICT' AS STMT
        from SYSCAT.ROUTINEAUTH 
        where grantee='PUBLIC' and schema='SYSPROC' and routinetype='P'
    DO
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v1.STMT;
    END FOR;
END#
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Since this isn't a creation of procedure, would I still run it with db2 -td# -svf RoutineAuthRevoke.db2, where this code would be in the file? 
I'm attempting to have this be run in a bat file as part of a security hardening suite which is why I wanted to create a procedure so I could do a "db2 call <procedurename>".

Comment: It's ok I tinkered around with it and managed to get it working using a batch file! Thank you so much for your answer, you've opened my eyes to an easier way of doing things and that'll save me heaps of time.